# Are these awk commands vulnerable to code injection?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, code-injection

I was unsure on how to correctly script a particular awk command which uses a shell variable, when I read the answers to [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/3258851).

The accepted answer demonstrates how interpolating a shell variable in an `awk`command would be prone to malicious code injection, and while I was able to reproduce the demo, I could not find the same problem with either of the following two commands:

```
#HWLINK=enp10s0
ip -o route | awk '/'$HWLINK'/ && ! /default/ {print $1}'
ip -o route | awk "/$HWLINK/"' && ! /default/ {print $1}'
```

So, the main question is if any of these (or both) is vulnerable.

A secondary question would be which form is preferred. I tried `ip -o route | awk -v hwlink="$HWLINK" '/hwlink/ && ! /default/ {print $1}'` but that doesn't work.

p.s. this is a refactoring; the original command was `ip -o route | grep $HWLINK | grep -v default | awk '{print $1}'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, both are vulnerable, the first a bit less so.

This breaks your second line:

```
HWLINK="/{}BEGIN{print \"Your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries\"}/"
```

The only reason it doesn't break your first line is, in order to be able to be injected into the first line it must not contain spaces.

```
HWLINK="/{}BEGIN{print\"Your_mother_was_a_hamster_and_your_father_smelt_of_elderberries\"}/"
```

I see you already got the correct syntax to use :)

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: Can you help me in getting it to run [sl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/sl.6.html)? I tried `HWLINK="\";sl -a;#"`. Didn't work.

Comment: That can't work - at this point, you're inside a regular expression, so `\"` just ends up trying to match a quote. What I do is breaking out of regular expression using `/{}`, which together with the existing `/` makes `//{}` (an empty regexp with empty statement); then use the `BEGIN{ ... }` to invoke awk code at the start; at the end, I use `/` again so that your closing `/` doesn't hang without a friend. Also, you're mixing up shell and awk; `sl` is a shell command, and you can't run it as if belongs there. You have to use `system` command. `"/{}BEGIN{system(\"sl -a\");exit}/"`

Comment: and now imagine the following code in the BEGIN statement `{system( "rm -rf *") }`

Comment: @kvantour: Indeed.

Comment: ITYM "the first a bit **more** so" since in the first one the variable is completely unquoted and so will have globbing, etc. performed on it while the 2nd one is at least inside double quotes.

Comment: @EdMorton: The issue is that _because_ it is unquoted, any space will _terminate_ the awk script; globbing won't really work if you can't have spaces to delimit it. E.g. if you tried to put in kvantour's `{system("rm -rf *")}`, the awk script would only be `//{}BEGIN{system("rm`, resulting in a syntax error. EDIT: HOWEVER, you could put a semicolon after the space and write plain bash command, which could indeed glob... ay ay ay, yes, you're right, it's _more_ so.

Comment: I guess which is worse just depends on what the attack looks like.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea was right about letting the shell variables getting interpolated inside `awk` could let malicious code injection. As rightly pointed use the `-v` syntax, but your attempt fails because the pattern match with variable doesn't work in the form `/../`, use the direct `~` match

```
ip -o route | awk -v hwlink="$HWLINK" '$0 ~ hwlink && ! /default/ {print $1}'
```

Recommended way to sanitize your variables passed to `awk` would be to use the `ARGV` array or `ENVIRON` variable. Variables passed this way don't undergo expansion done by the shell

```
value='foo\n\n'
awk 'BEGIN {var=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]}' "$value"
```

If you printed the value of `var` inside the `awk` it would be a literal `foo\n\n` and *not* the multi-line string which usually happens when the shell expands it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had somewhat of a hard time picking one, since both were helpful (and are equally upvoted). This time I went with the other one but you do have my upvote. p.s.: great profile pic!